# Elasticsearch using a result of a query as input in an other query

Tags: elasticsearch

Can I store a result of an aggregation query to use it as an input in an other query? Is this possible? I am using Elasticsearch 1.5.2.

Comment: No. You will have to make two queries to achieve this.

Comment: I need that my second query concern only the result of my first query, not all the documents. I must minimize the execution time of my queries.

Comment: Can you please explain in a bit more detail. From what I understand, your first query is an aggregation and the result of that aggregation is used as an input to your second query. Correct me if I m wrong

Comment: My first query is an aggregation, I want to store its result somehow to make an other query only on this result. It's like creating a new index which contains only this result to search on it.